# Почему метод findById() не работает и выбрасывает ошибку?

Tags: kotlin, spring-boot

Есть 1 сущность, есть репа, которая отвечает за CRUD-операции с этой сущностью. Методы `save`, `findAll` отрабатывают нормально, а `findById` выкидывает исключение, типа не может найти требуемый `id`  для сущности.

В чем проблема?

```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at ru.home.kotlincoreexample.core.LaunchAppKt.main(LaunchApp.kt:27) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required identifier property not found for class ru.home.kotlincoreexample.core.repository.domain.Person
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PersistentEntity.getRequiredIdProperty(PersistentEntity.java:135) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.support.SimpleR2dbcRepository.lambda$new$0(SimpleR2dbcRepository.java:83) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:231) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.support.SimpleR2dbcRepository.getIdProperty(SimpleR2dbcRepository.java:453) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.support.SimpleR2dbcRepository.getIdQuery(SimpleR2dbcRepository.java:457) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.support.SimpleR2dbcRepository.findById(SimpleR2dbcRepository.java:187) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
```

**LaunchApp.kt**

```
package ru.home.kotlincoreexample.core

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import ru.home.kotlincoreexample.core.repository.domain.PersonRepository

@SpringBootApplication
class LaunchApp(var personRepository: PersonRepository) : CommandLineRunner {
    override fun run(vararg args: String?) {
        println("Person id = ${personRepository.findById(1L).block()}")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<LaunchApp>(*args)
}
```

**Person.kt**

```
package ru.home.kotlincoreexample.core.repository.domain

import lombok.ToString
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.R2dbcRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import javax.persistence.*


@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@ToString
class Person(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    val id: Long,
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
    val nationality: String
)

@Repository
interface PersonRepository : R2dbcRepository<Person, Long>
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.14.RELEASE"
    id ("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.7.20"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.20"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.7.20"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.7.20"

}

allOpen {
    annotations("javax.persistence.Entity", "javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass", "javax.persistence.Embedabble")
}

group = "ru.abc"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table

@Table(name = "tb_person")
data class Person (
    @Id
    var id: Long,
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
    val nationality: String
) {
```

Убрать из **build.gradle.kts** `implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")`
И заменить аннотация из пакета `import javax.persistence.*` на `import org.springframework.data.*`